# django jwt "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt

I am trying to implement jwt token authentication in my Django Rest Framework application. I am able to receive a token from the django server as you can see POSTMAN request but when I try to get user profile, I got this error. Does anyone have idea??

{ "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided." }

[image]

I could get access token as you can see.

[image]

This is SIMPLE_JWT setting in settings.py

```py
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(hours=1),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=3),
    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('JWT', ),
    'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken', )
}
```

This is app/urls.py

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("api/", include("user.api.urls")),
    path('api/auth/', include('djoser.urls')),
    path('api/auth/', include('djoser.urls.jwt')),
]
```

This is app/user/urls.py

```py
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register("api/auth/users/", TraineeRegisterApiView)

urlpatterns = [
    path('profile/', TraineeProfileApiView.as_view({'get': 'retrieve'}))
]
```

Maybe it is because of the trainee models below, but I do not how to fix it....

```py
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Email is necessary')

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        email = email.lower()
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        user = self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save()

        return user


class Trainee(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    trainee = models.BooleanField("trainee", default=True)
    # TODO create Order class
    # trainer = models.ForeignKey(
    #     Trainer, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    # )
    user_name = models.CharField("user_name", max_length=255, null=False)
    first_name = models.CharField("first_name", max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField("email", max_length=255, unique=True)
    last_name = models.CharField("last_name", max_length=255)
    height = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100, decimal_places=1, null=True, blank=True)
    weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100, decimal_places=1, null=True, blank=True)
    goal_setting = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='PowerLifting')
    dob = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, default="Male")

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['user_name', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'height', 'weight']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

This is serializer.py

```py
User = get_user_model()


class TraineeRegisterSerializer(BaseUserRegistrationSerializer):
    class Meta:
        models = User
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True, 'required': True}}


class TraineeProfileSerializer(UserSerializer):
    class Meta:
        models = User
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True, 'required': True}}
```

This is my view.py

```py
# Register API
class TraineeRegisterApiView(views.UserViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = TraineeRegisterSerializer


class TraineeProfileApiView(views.UserViewSet):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = TraineeProfileSerializer
```

Comment: Have you added the SimpleJWT authentication class as per [the install instructions](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#installation)?

Comment: Thank you so much for a quick response!!
I think it's correct because the access token is coming back. I've looked at the documentation for djoser and I think it's correct.
https://djoser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/authentication_backends.html#json-web-token-authentication

Comment: Please show your `REST_FRAMEWORK = ...` configuration in `settings.py` too. If you don't have the authentication class, no REST Framework view will _accept_ a token.

Comment: This is from settings.py.
```python
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASS': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASS': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    )
}
```

Comment: Okay – can you try using Postman's Authentication > Bearer option instead of manually adding the header in Postman? I think Postman may be overwriting the header.

Comment: umm, it did not work as well...